# Problems with saving content in a check list Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried to make a ToDo-list in my App. Her is the code I have been using.
Everythins seems to work just fine when i run the code on both my iPhone and the iOS simulator. But the problem iss that all the tasks I have added to the ToDo-list dissapears as soon as I exit the app or go to another view. Does anyone knows a way I can iplement a save-function to this code?
Thank you very much.

```
#import "TODOViewController.h"

@interface TODOViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *categories;

@end

@implementation TODOViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.items = @[@{@"name" : @"Take out the trash", @"category" : @"home"}, @{@"name" : @"Take out the trash", @"category" : @"home"}, @{@"Name" : @"Reply to that important email", @"category" : @"work"}].mutableCopy;
self.categories = @[@"Oppgaver", @""];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Huskeliste";

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem:)];





// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a      little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/



#pragma mark - Adding items
- (void)addNewItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ny     hendelse" message:@"Skriv inn navnet på den nye hendelsen" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Avbryt" otherButtonTitles:@"Legg til hendelse", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alertView show];




}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:    (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
    UITextField *itemNameField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSString *itemName = itemNameField.text;
    NSDictionary *item = @{@"name" : itemName, @"category" : @"Oppgaver"};
    [self.items addObject:item];
    NSInteger numHomeItems = [self numberOfItemsInCategory:@"Oppgaver"];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:numHomeItems - 1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}






}

#pragma mark - Datasource helper methods

- (NSArray *)itemsInCategory: (NSString *)targetCategory {
NSPredicate *matchingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category     ==%@", targetCategory];
NSArray *categoryItems = [self.items     filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matchingPredicate];

return categoryItems;


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCategory: (NSString *)targetCategory {
return [self itemsInCategory:targetCategory].count;
}

- (NSDictionary *)itemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *category = self.categories[indexPath.section];
NSArray *categoryItems = [self itemsInCategory:category];
NSDictionary *item = categoryItems[indexPath.row];


return item;
}

- (NSInteger)itemIndexForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSInteger index = [self.items indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:item];

return index;
}

- (void)removeItemsAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger index = [self itemIndexForIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.items removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

#pragma mark - Table view datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return self.categories.count;



}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self numberOfItemsInCategory:self.categories[section]];



}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TodoItemRow";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = item[@"name"];

if ([item[@"completed"] boolValue]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}

return cell;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.categories[section];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger index = [self itemIndexForIndexPath:indexPath];
NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.items[index] mutableCopy];
BOOL completed = [item[@"completed"] boolValue];
item[@"completed"] = @(!completed);

self.items[index] = item;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = ([item[@"completed"]boolValue]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
    [self removeItemsAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
}

@end
```

Comment: Please narrow down the code in your question to just the parts relevant to your question. Point out what you have tried to do to save new data. What issue are you having with the code that saves data?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to implement persistence.
There are some native things such as [User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) and [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).
Perhaps for this simple exercise you could just use User Defaults.
Here's an example of how to use User Defaults.

```
- (void)refreshData {
    self.items = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"TodoItems"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)addTodoItem {
    // Show Prompt
    NSString *newTodoItem; //= Result of prompt
    // Get the current Todo Items
    NSArray *currentTodoItems = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"TodoItems"];
    // Add the newest Todo Item
    NSArray *updatedTodoItems = [currentTodoItems arrayByAddingObject:newTodoItem];

    // Update the previous Todo Array with the updated one
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:updatedTodoItems forKey:@"TodoItems"];
    // Save
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // Update the TableView to show the newly added Todo Item
    [self refreshData];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. im very new to this, so i am learning by viewing tutorials. Where in the code should i implement this code you posted? And what modifications do i have to do with it?

Comment: @Simen did you end up implementing a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's loads of different ways to save data and you need to pick the best one for your purposes. First, instead of having an array of dictionaries I would make a custom `ToDo` object and use that as your model for entries in the to do list. Then you need to decide:

1) How much data will you be saving?

2) Will you be loading everything at once or bits at a time?

If it is relatively small amounts of data then you could use an [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html) approach.

If it is larger amounts of data you may want to look at [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) or [Sqlite](https://sqlite.org).

Other options are .plists or .txt or .csv files (any format you like really), which all have their pros and cons and are suited to different tasks.